# How can I create a JSON object and use it to update an ng-repeat?

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I want to create a JSON object and then use that object to update my `ng-repeat` (i.e., prepend the `ng-repeat` with the info inside the JSON object). Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
var data1 = 'value1';
var data2 = 'value2';
var data3 = 'value3';
var json = {'item1':data1,
            'item2':data2,
            'item2':data3};
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
$scope.things.unshift(obj[0]);
```

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    {{thing.item1}} <br>
    {{thing.item2}} <br>
    {{thing.item3}} <br>
</div>
```

The idea is that I'm using `$scope.things.unshift(obj[0]);` to UPDATE the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `JSON.parse` -- that is already JavaScript constructs.  Using `[0]` is also wrong because this is an *object*, not an array.  This means that you should be able to do `{{thing}}` rather than `{{thing.item1}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I removed ``[0]`` and I no longer run it through ``JSON.parse``, but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Well `obj` is an object, so you probably don't want to use `unshift`.  Maybe just `$scope.things = obj`.

Comment: That change didn't work. Also, I want to prepend ``obj`` to an already existing list (generated from ``ng-repeat``). Is there an "object version" of ``unshift``?

Comment: @ChrisPaterson no that wouldn't make any sense since object elements aren't ordinal.  For objects you would just do `obj[propName] = propValue`

Comment: Okay thanks. I'm still not sure how I can update my ``ng-repeat`` list. That is, append ``obj`` to the top of the list. Should I use an array instead of an object?

Comment: @ChrisPaterson probably yes.  Just keep in mind that `unshift` works on elements not arrays, so you would have to use `$scope.thing.unshift.apply($scope.thing, objArray)`

Answer (score 0):

$scope.things = [ {thing1: 'value1', thing2: 'value2', thing3: 'value3'}, {thing1: 'value4', thing2: 'value5', thing3: 'value6'}];